# Where do the Gradle build-in functions come from?

Tags: gradle

I am reading gradle book and it says:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task customJar(type: Jar) {
    ...
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/jars")
    ...
}
```

> The  `file()` method, which is always available inside a Gradle
>   build file

So my question is where does this method come from? Where is it defined and why is it visible to the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file()` method comes from [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) class (as many other methods). Basically if there's no object defined before method invocation there's a big likelihood that this method is invoked on `project` object which is a `Project` class instance.